# how to store information to dbf files by iraninanSystem codePage

Tags: c#, dbf

I am bound to Dbf file by the below code and store my information

```
    public int save_dbf_func(string source_dbf, string str_command)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + source_dbf + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=;"); // give your path directly 
            OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
            Cmd.CommandText = str_command;
            Cmd.Connection = con;
            int RowEffect = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return RowEffect;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var mm = ex.ToString();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

for example :

```
save_dbf_func("c:\folder", "insert into file.dbf (fName , lName) values ('مرتضی' , 'زند')")
```

And by a dll convert my string to Iranian system codePage for example:

```
    CONVERTLib.ConvertorClass convert_dll = new CONVERTLib.ConvertorClass();

        textBox1.Text = convert_dll.WinToIran('مرتضی');
```

converted string into the textbox is correct but when I store the string in the Dbf file for most characters show ???? ??? ?????.

Please guide me how to make the information stored in the database that they are not damaged.

Thanks

Comment: salam, mitoni link download in dll WinToIran ro be man bedi? inam email man: askari.2006@gmail.com

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store unicode text in DBF file, it only allows to store ANSI characters. So you should convert iranian unicode text to ANSI charset before inserting into a DBF file. Also don't forget to set 1256 Arabic Windows charset flag in your result DBF file.